# Is there a trick to iterate a set of multidimensional values with \psforeach?

Tags: pstricks

I have, for example, a set of multidimensional values: `{{red,1,12pt},{blue,3,10pt},{green,2,15pt}}`. With `\psforeach` I want to iterate the values with 3 variables: `\clr`, `\x`, and `\size`.

Is there a trick to iterate a set of multidimensional values with `\psforeach`?

---

Edit: By combining the existing answers, the following is the result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=12pt
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}


\def\getValues#1,#2,#3\relax{\def\clr{#1}\def\x{#2}\def\size{#3}}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](-3,-3)(3,3)
    \@for\abc:={{red,1,12pt},{blue,3,10pt},{green,2,15pt}}% this percent sign is needed!
    \do{\expandafter\getValues\abc\relax
        \pscircle[linecolor=\clr,linewidth=\size](0,0){\x}
        % other graphics objects go here!
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you can split the argument of `psforeach` with something like this: `\def\tempa#1,#2,#3{\def\clr{#1}\def\x{#2}\def\size{#3}}\tempa\argumentofpsforeach\relax`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Could you show the complete solution as an answer?

Comment: @Forgiver: you can simplify it with `\do{\expandafter\psCircle\abc\relax}` and `\def\psCircle#1,#2,#3\relax{\pscircle[linecolor=#1,linewidth=#3]{#2}}
`

Comment: @Herbert:But I need `\clr`, `\x`, and `\size` for other usage.

Comment: ok, then you're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

only the first argument has to be put into double braces:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\def\temp#1{\expandafter\tempB#1\relax}
\def\tempB#1,#2,#3\relax{Colour: #1; X: #2; Size: #3 \par} 
\begin{document}
\psforeach{\abc}{{{red,1,12pt}},{blue,3,10pt},{green,2,15pt}}{%
  \expandafter\temp\expandafter{\abc}}

\end{document}
```

and the same without loading any package:

```
\documentclass{minimal} 
\def\tempB#1,#2,#3\relax{Colour: #1; X: #2; Size: #3 \par}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter 
\@for\abc:={{red,1,12pt},{blue,3,10pt},{green,2,15pt}}%
  \do{\expandafter\tempB\abc\relax}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But why does the first element have to be enclosed by an extra pair of braces?

Comment: the first argument is expanded to see if there is something like 1,..,3. However, you can call it a bug or a feature ... :-)

Comment: Hopefully this bug fix will be announced in the incoming `pst-news`. :-)

Comment: I'll do my very best ... :-)

Answer (score 3):

How about using `pgffor`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\def\tempa#1,#2,#3\relax{\def\clr{#1}\def\x{#2}\def\size{#3}}
\foreach \abc in {{red,1,12pt},{blue,3,10pt},{green,2,15pt}}{
  \expandafter\tempa\abc\relax%
  Colour: \clr; X: \x; Size: \size\par
}%
\end{document}
```

Each element in `\foreach`, called `\abc` is expanded and passed to `\tempa`, which breaks it up into the three components as `\clr`, `\x`, `\size`.

Answer (score 1):

The macro `\cptdofunclist` doesn't need any delimiter on the last argument of `\do`. It can see.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\def\do#1,#2,#3{Colour: #1; X: #2; Size: #3\par}
\cptdofunclist[;]{red, 1, 12pt; blue, 3, 10pt; green, 2, 15pt}

\par\bigskip
\def\do#1,#2,#3,#4{\scalebox{#3}[#4]{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}}
\cptdofunclist[;]{red, Red, 2, 3; blue, Blue, 4, 5; green, Green, 6, 7}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, if you insist on using **pgffor**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\def\tempa(#1,#2,#3){Colour: #1; X: #2; Size: #3\par}
\foreach \abc in {(red,1,12pt),(blue,3,10pt),(green,2,15pt)}{%
  \expandafter\tempa\abc\relax
}
\end{document}
```